# std::vector .size() returns garbage when copied (compiled on linux vs VS)

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, stdvector

In an implementation of Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm I've been working on, I've run into an issue I can't seem to pinpoint the source of.

In the meat of the algorithm, a copy of the graph is made so that elements can be pulled off from the top of the copy without damaging the original (I've been using a fairly standard min-heap). Since it doesn't need to live beyond the scope of the function, I figured it'd be fine to store it on the stack. As such, my call was:

```
heap Q = this->graph.heap;
```

A graph consists of, along with it's member functions, a single `heap` field.

A heap consists of a single `std::vector<vertex> heep` onto which the elements are added and maintained.
Vertex is a struct:

```
struct vertex{
     int distance;
     int prev;
     int name;
     std::vector<edge> adj;
};
```

Likewise, for edge:

```
struct edge{
     int left;
     int right;
     int weight;
};
```

When compiling running in visual studio, everything copies perfectly. However, when running/compiling on my school's server, a linux based system, the biggest problem is that the size of the `vert.adj.size();` returns absolute garbage for all `adj` other than those of size two. From what I can tell, all of the other fields of the heap are copying correctly (edge's connected nodes and weights are all in the list). But for any `adj` whose size *should* be anything other than size `2`, `.size()` is returning something closer to 6 billion.

Input from an instructor was that I forgot to dynamically allocate memory to `Q`, and not having the proper memory allocated is leading to misreads. I was under the impression that this was only necessary for pointers, and not for objects on stack memory.

Any guesses? I'm more than willing to share any additional code, but it's become bastardized enough from the original through the debugging process that I only figured to share what seems necessary. If it was a memory allocation problem, I'm sure Visual Studio would have been just as angry at me as anything else, wouldn't it?

Comment: Provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'll get right on it.

Comment: I would start with the copy constructor of the `heap` class. If there's an allocation error that's where it would be.

Comment: Related to this problem you can check the following link. [c++ garbage values in vector of pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33366877/c-garbage-values-in-vector-of-pointer)

Comment: Please go through the following link [c++ garbage values in vector of pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33366877/c-garbage-values-in-vector-of-pointer)